# Can't flash my Android device with custom ROM using fastboot, (remote: file too large)

Tags: android, adb, fastboot

My android device (Huawei Y6 2018 ATU-L21) is already unlocked and in fastboot mode, I followed [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-lineageos-15-0-huawei-y6-2018.3811575/) guide, but when I type `fastboot flash -S 256M system image.img`, this happens:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash -S 256M system image.img
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
sending sparse 'system' 1/7 (262140 KB)...
OKAY [  9.113s]
writing 'system' 1/7...
FAILED (remote: size too large)
finished. total time: 9.146s
```

I'm new to this so I don't have any idea what I could do. Yes, I'm running the cmd as administrator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update [platform-tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip) or try smaller size. or flash from TWRP